# listview selection color in android

Tags: android, css, listview, android-listview, colors

in my listview, when user long press on a item, i draw a custom actionbar and provide user option to delete multiple items at a time.

by default if i perform long press action, i will get selection color as blue and it gets disappear.

To overcome i tried adding a selector like this.

listviewselector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/RED"/> 

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@color/BLUE" /> 

</selector>
```

If i set this selector, when user performs long press i can see red color, but after wards if user performs selection, no color is getting retained on item. By default it looks white.

I tried setting background color based on condition like below

```
   if(mSelectedItemsIds.get(key))
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(REDCOLOR);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(WHITE);
        }
```

In this case, if user performs long press and then if user select multiple items i could see red color and by default all the items color will be white. But if user touches any item the default color will be nothing i.e no color appears on selection.

How to get default white color, on tap blue color and upon multiple selection red color?

**i tried like this**
New selector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/RED"/> 

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@color/WHITE" /> 

</selector> 



 if(mSelectedItemsIds.get(key))
            {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.RED));
            }
            else
            {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.listviewselector);
            }
```

In this i get by default all items blue color. why?

Comment: try setting the listselector to the xml file inflated by convertView

Comment: any sample code please.. thanks

Comment: listviewselector.xml that you posted  is the sample by the way I am a naruto fan too

Comment: Yes, THanks me too huge fan of Naruto... Thanks :).. But sample example i tried like this. i have edited the ans please see. i'm getting default blue color for all items.

Comment: i meant to add android:background="@drawable/listviewselector.xml" in the xml file of the custom row so that every item in your listview has them. Then as soon you detect a longpress you can change background color from java

Comment: i tried setting as background to my item linearlayout, no luck :(

Comment: Hey, it worked. i have posted answer. Thanks for ur help. Naruto fans Rocks :)

Answer (score 1):

i tried like this, it worked.

```
if(mSelectedItemsIds.get(key))
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.BLUE));
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
        }
```

Comment: I was also trying it seems like I dont need to do it. Well I am your jiriya lol

Comment: Hmm, +1 for ur comment :)